# events flow of Panel in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my application architecture.

```
var loginView = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    id: 'LoginView',
    .....
});
var homeView = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
    id: 'HomeView',
    items: [
           {
                xtype: 'list',
                title: 'Home',
                store: Ext.create('TweetStore'),
                disableSelection: true,
                ....
            },
            {
                title: 'Reply',
                ....
            },
            {
                title: 'DM',
                ....
            }
    ]
});
var mainView = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    id: 'MainView',
    layout: 'card',
    items: [ loginView, mainView ]
});
Ext.define('TweetStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        config: {
            fields: ...
            pageSize: 25,
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/home',
                pageParam: 'page',
                limitParam: 'count',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

There are two panels in `MainView`. `LoginView` is a login page where user input his username and password. When the authorization succeed, the second panel `HomeView` shows.

My questions:

1. I want the data in `TweetStore` to be loaded after the authorization, that is, when the `HomeView` shows, the data begins to load. But the `show` event is triggered even the
   panel is still hidden. What event should I catch.
2. When the application starts, I want to send a ajax request to check whether the user is login, if true, the `LoginView` hide and the `HomeView` shows. In which event should I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. 1) You should listen for **[`painted()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-painted)** event.

> Fires whenever this Component actually becomes visible (painted) on
>   the screen. This is useful when you need to perform 'read' operations
>   on the DOM element, i.e: calculating natural sizes and positioning.

Q. 2) Send the ajax request for user authentication on [`initialize()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-initialize) event.

> Fires when the component has been initialized

Comment: Thank you~ Q1: should I change something in `TweetScore`? now it is auto loaded, just when the application begins. Q2: initialize() event in which view? `MainView` or `LoginView`? since I realize that LoginView is initialized first.

Answer (score 0):

**- 1st question:**

`painted` event seems good but in fact, it's terribly full of bugs in current release of Sencha Touch 2, as my experience. Do NOT rely on its existence and documentation.

According to what you've described, it's clear that you want to load your store after a specific event (authorization), so how about firing a custom event after that? For example:

`loginForm.fireEvent('authenticated', this)` (or any extra-params you need)

then in your controller, just listen to event `authenticated` on `loginForm` view.

**- 2nd question:**

As you said, you want to run  some processes right after your application started. So the right place to put your code is in `launch()` function of your `app.js`. Just simple.